# Send mails with a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, postfix-mta

My webapp is running on Rails 3.0.3 with MySQL on a ubuntu server.

I want to send mails from my website. On the webserver i intalled postfix. I can send mails with the command line.

all my .rb in environements have the following lines :

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "localhost",
  :port                 => "25",
  :domain               => 'mydomain.com'
  }
```

It does not work when i send a mail from the Rails console, it says it sended a mail and that's all :

```
=> #<Mail::Message:83356150, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: Some One <someone@mydomain.com>>, <To: my@mail.com>, <Subject: sending mails!>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/plain>>
```

There is no trace in \var\log\mail.log, there is not trace in log/test.log in the rails app.

I do not know where to go. Is it my rails config? is it my postfix? Is it a network issue?

I only want to send mail from the webapp so i tried with sendmail, but it did not work too.

**EDIT:** On my dev environnement, i have a trace in my logs about mails :

```
Rendered notifier/email.text.erb (7.3ms)
```

Launching the correct console (rails c test) i can find the same trace in my test environement. But my postfix logs are still untouched by rails...

Answer (score 0):

Check `config/environments/development.rb` (i think thats the directory).

Make sure

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

These will override the settings in config/environment.rb

Comment: Already using that folder. Mais settings are in test, develop and production.rb. Despite raise error, log/test.log remain empty.